# How does this code to check for balanced parenthesis work?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Here's the problem I was working on: http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=188

Here's the solution: http://usaco.org/current/data/sol_typo.html

I cannot understand the logic behind the solution. Can anyone please explain the solution with detail?

I'm new to solving these problems, but I am trying to prepare for my first USACO competition in November. Just for clarification purposes, I'm writing the solutions in C++.

Comment: No, I don't understand it. That's why I posted here. Why does answer = closingSeen if depth = -1? Same question goes with the other assignments. @user2864740

Comment: My question really pertains to the logic of the program in general. That is, how does the concept of openingSeen and closingSeen relate to finding the answer? @user2864740

Comment: Ahh, I see - "Why not just depth?" Because it asks for the number of reversals to balance it, if any. Try to solve a few cases like `))))` / `))()))` (two open reversals) and `((((` / `((()((` (two close reversals) by hand.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but I think I'm not being clear enough on what I'm asking for. Here's an itemized list of questions:
1. Why does answer = openingSeen if depth > 1?
2. Why does answer = closingSeen if depth = -1?
3. Why is openingSeen = 0 if depth <= 1?
4. How would I derive a solution like this during the time of an actual competition?

Comment: Your question is currently very dependent on external resources, which is not appropriate for [so]. Please put the problem statement and solution in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

For a string to have balanced parenthesis, you need two things: an equal number of `(` and `)`, and every `(` can be matched with at least one `)` to the right of it.

Another way to look at it is to treat `(` as `+1` and `)` as `-1`. As you process parenthesis one at a time, add or subtract 1, depending on its sign, starting at 0. If the sum ever drops below 0 (which can only happen if you hit a `)`, you know that if you can reverse one parenthesis to balance the string, it will be that one. Once you hit this point, you reset the sum to zero. If the sum drops below zero again, it won't ever be balanced, so you can early out.

The other case you need to deal with is where switching a `(` to `)` will balance the string. You can only do this if the sum at the end is 2, so you track the last `(` you saw while the sum is >=2. If the sum is ever < 2, you cannot switch that `(`.

If the sum at the end is less than zero, the string will not be balanced. If the sum at the end is zero, then if you found one parenthesis to reverse, that's the one to reverse. Otherwise, if it's `2`, you can swap the last `(` you found to balance the string.

Comment: THANK YOU! That was very helpful! I just have two more questions... What is the answer if the sum is less than zero? What are the roles of openingSeen and closingSeen?

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of openingSeen is, since you don't really need it.

Comment: But there's a statement near the end that reads:
if(depth > 0)       ans = openingSeen

Comment: Ah, that's the other edge case mentioned in #2 in the solution.

Comment: from what you have said in your answer, "if the sum drops below zero again, it won't ever be balanced, so you can early out." Take a look at this case: ())))). The sum drops below zero twice, yet it is still possible to balance it.